# Make a cog that sends a message every 10 seconds in a specified chat discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.8

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks



class sendmessage10seconds(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        print("Cog is running")


    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def sendmessage(ctx, self):
        channel = self.get_channel(802273252973477960)
        await channel.send("Hi")
    sendmessage.start()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(sendmessage10seconds(client))
```

This is my code so far. When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sendmessage() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'self'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1. `self` goes always as a first argument, not second

```py
async def sendmessage(self, ctx):
```

2. You need to pass the `ctx` parameter, when starting the task (or don't pass it at all, there's no need for that)
3. There's no such thing as `self.get_channel` (remember, you're not inheriting from `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot`), it's `self.client.get_channel`

```py
channel = self.client.get_channel(...)
```

4. You need to start the task in a function or a command

```py
@commands.command()
async def start(self, ctx):
    self.sendmessage.start() # Pass the `ctx` parameter accordingly
```

EDIT: Starting the loop in the `__init__` method

```py
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.sendmessages.start()
```

*Note: you should add wait until the bot is ready loading the internal cache, one way of doing that is using the decorator `{task}.before_loop` and using `Bot.wait_until_ready`*

```py
@sendmessage.before_loop
async def before_sendmessage(self):
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
```

Your full fixed code

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class sendmessage10seconds(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.sendmessage.start()


    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def sendmessage(self): # You can pass the `ctx` parameter if you want, but there's no point in doing that
        channel = self.client.get_channel(802273252973477960)
        await channel.send("Hi")


    @sendmessage.before_loop
    async def before_sendmessage(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(sendmessage10seconds(client))
```

Comment: There isn't an error but nothing is happening. No message is being sent, the cog is running though(i put a print statement in __init__)

Comment: Well, you have to use the `start` command in order to start it

Comment: Another way is to start it in the `__init__` method, but you should then wait until the bot is ready, with `bot.wait_until_ready` so the cache is fully loaded, let me edit my answer for that

Comment: I added "sendmessage.start()" after the sendmessage function on the same indent level as @tasks.loop. It outputed this error:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'sendmessage'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sendmessage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: it's `self.sendmessage.start`, like in the code I showed you

Comment: That isn't doing anything either, once again the cog is running but even with the new code the task is not running.

Comment: Edited my answer, also - you should learn more python, this is a basic OOP concept, discord.py is heavy based on those concepts, you should learn more before diving deeper into discord bots

Comment: Also I tried the code, it works perfectly [fine](https://streamable.com/ch3jgm)